# How do I extract a substring from a string in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I want to write a message in a textarea and be able to refer to a person using the @ symbol.

e.g

> Please call @Larry David regarding
>   something

When submitting the form, I want to extract the persons name ie Larry David.

How do I go about extracting this string with Jquery?

Comment: What if the person name is `Larry David Regarding`? I think the best you can do here is to extract `Larry`.

Comment: what do you think of using the same mechanism as SO uses for tags (i.e. smart autocompletion)? it's not an easy thing to do right though

Comment: why with jQuery?? using a regex would be more efficient like the example in the answer below..

Comment: What are valid names? Does the name always matches a username on database or something?

Answer (score 5):

What if the person name is `Larry David Regarding`? I think the best you can do here is to extract `Larry`:

```
var result = $('#textareaId').val().match(/\@(\w+)/);
if (result != null && result.length > 1) {
    alert(result[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well to match what you asked for it would be:

```
var str = "Please call @Larry David regarding something";
var re = /@(\w+\s\w+)/;

var name = str.match(re);
if(name){
    alert(name[1])
}
```

But it would fail for names like foo-bar, O'Donald, etc.

A regular expression such as

```
var re = /@(\w+\s[\w-']+)/;
```

would be a little better, but still will fail with other names.

Without a better way of figuring out where the name ends, you may have errors with names.